# Multiple discounts or admin only pricing?

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

I'm creating an event that has a surcharge for registering at the door. I'm thinking of using CiviDiscount to create an automatic discount on the registration price set, then expiring the discount after normal online registration expires. However, I also have another automatic discount for a membership type. Can I combine the discounts this way? Will I be better served by creating an admin only option for registering attendees at the door instead of having only one price set that has the discounts applied to it?

Comment: just a thought. have you considered using Early Bird Pricing that eg runs to 1 hour before event? and therefore charges full amount 'at the door', or do you want to allow folk to register 'online' from the car park before they walk to the door.

Comment: any maybe clarify what 'at the door reg' looks like - do you have someone on the door, if so are they doing 'back end' rego or still using the public forms, or do you have public devices for folk to 'self register at the door'? Not sure i know how to help but trying to tease out the options

Comment: Both great comments. Essentially, I'm thinking of exactly that, having the early bird expire either hours or a couple days (like close of business on the preceding Friday) before the event. The association will be doing back end registrations at the event for the at the door pricing. So, this could be done with the addition of a back end only price for the late comer. It seems more elegant, if I can just automate the pricing on a schedule, but I don't know what's best practice for a situation like this.

Comment: What does "automate the pricing on a schedule" mean? CiviEvent offers Early Bird pricing, as do Price Sets, so you mean something else?

Comment: Just scheduling the discount to expire. We know when the conference will be, and we set an end date to the current discount, so that the client doesn't need to manually login to discontinue the discount.

Comment: CiviEvent offers Early Bird pricing, as do Price Sets,https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/events/complex-event-fees/